# Does Firefox have a shortcut for deleting the current line?

Tags: firefox

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> in Sublime text, the line in which the cursor is gets deleted. Is there a similar shortcut for Firefox when the cursor is in a textarea?

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Del</kbd> seems to remove the word right of the cursor.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: [Keyboard shortcuts - Perform common Firefox tasks quickly](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly#w_editing)

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+<left arrow>, then Del may do the work (if you are on the end of the line). In case you are on the begin you can use right arrow